# c# GetResponse() timeout, but works on browser

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to read the response i get from nyc.gov. I used Fiddler to construct the WebRequest and it keeps timing out.
**Important**: this works if the url is https://www.google.com so it's got to be something from the nyc.gov server. But how can it know the difference between my code and Chrome?

I tried settings the KeepAlive to true/false/none.
I tried using Http1.0
I tried setting request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue to false
I tried setting request.ContentLength = 0;
I tried enclosing in "using"
I added to app.config

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="1000" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

Here is my code:

```
 try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/bispi00.jsp");

                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", @"1");
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36";
                request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3";
                request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
                request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.9");

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
                else return false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (response != null) response.Close();
                return false;
            }
```

Here is the RAW request (provided by Fiddler) from Chrome - WORKS:

```
GET http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/bispi00.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: a810-bisweb.nyc.gov
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

And this is the RAW request from my code - HANGS (and eventually times out)

```
 GET http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/bispi00.jsp HTTP/1.1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Host: a810-bisweb.nyc.gov
Connection: Keep-Alive
```